# How do I setup environment variable INCLUDE for Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, environment-variables

Is there a script that I can run that will setup my %INCLUDE% environment variable?

I'm running [PC-lint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC-Lint) and it can't find my include header files. I went through the documentation and it appears that I need to setup the %INCLUDE% environment variable.
I was wondering if there's an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio comes with a `VCVARS32` (it might be renamed by now) batch file in its directory that will set all of these environment variables for you, and give you a shell with them set.  It has a start menu entry, if you installed normally -- or maybe it came with the Platform SDK?  It's been a while.

From the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt(VS.80).aspx) on the subject:

> **To run vcvars32.bat**
>
> 1. At the command prompt, change to the \bin subdirectory of your Visual C++ installation.
> 2. Run vcvars32.bat by typing `VCVARS32`.

Barring that, you can permanently set your environment variables (per-system or per-user) in Control Panel, under System.

Comment: right, and that's what I want to do is to set it permanently.
so I was hoping that by running vcvars32 it would enter them into the environment vars under system

Comment: No, it won't. You'd have to do that yourself.